# ¿Cómo puedo extraer una string?

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que tengo:

```
var ob = {}

edad: 16,
nombre: 'Eduardo Sebastian'

};

for (var i in ob) {

var e = i.slice(1,2);

console.log(e);

}
```

> Lo unico que hago es crear un objeto, recorrerlo y mostrar la segunda
>   letra de sus propiedades. Pero como hago para mostrar el nombre entero
>   de la propiedad, pero con la segunda letra en mayuscula. Y otra aparte
>   con la segunda y tercera mayuscula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Usando slice y toUpperCase()

```js
var ob = {
    edad: 16,
    nombre: 'Eduardo Sebastian'
};

//segunda letra i[1] en mayúscula
for (var i in ob) {
    var e = i.slice(1,2);
    console.log(i[0]+i[1].toUpperCase()+i.slice(2));
}

//segunda y tercera letra i.slice(1,3) en mayúscula
for (var i in ob) {
    var e = i.slice(1,2);
    console.log(i[0]+i.slice(1,3).toUpperCase()+i.slice(3));
}
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar Stack Snippet? En esta respuesta de meta comparto algo de información sobre esta función -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1450/65

Comment: No lo conocía. Muy interesante. Gracias @Rubén

Comment: Uy qué bueno https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ ahora que lo probé no creo que use otra cosa (salvo para postgresql) ¿alguna sugerencia para postgres u otro sql?

Comment: Que bueno que te gustó. Por el momento no tengo sugerencias de algo similar para eso, lo único que conozco es el resaltado de sintaxis.

Comment: Gracias Emilio ,